# Communicate with a REST service inside a REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, channelfactory

i use the following code to communicate with a REST service:

```
[ServiceContract()]
interface ISomeService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    [WebGet()]
    bool DoSomething();
}

WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
ChannelFactory<ISomeService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>(binding, "http://localhost:12000");
channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
ISomeService service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
service.DoSomething();
```

It works fine in simple test applications, but in my real application i want to call it inside my own REST service: If a call to my REST service is made, my service should make a call to another REST service.

And there things go weird. In this situation the code above does not work because if it is placed inside a service method it sends a POST request instead of a GET request, which of course results in a "Method not allowed" error. I don't have the attribute WebInvoke anywhere in my code.

```
[ServiceContract()]
class MainService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    [WebGet()]
    public void Test()
    {
        CallDoSomething(); // code from above: Sends POST instead of GET request
    }
}
```

How can it be that the HTTP request method changes?

Comment: Dors `ISomeService` have `[WebGet]` on its operations? On the client side.

Comment: Yep, it has [WebGet] on both sides :) I added a demo to the start post.